# Woocommerce Apply Coupon Automaticly for Specific Mobile Number

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I have an API where I will have a verification process, Only some listed customer's phone number will be placed in that API. If that customer's number is in that API, a pre-generated coupon code will automaticly applied in the customer's cart.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
function verify_api_phonenumber($customer_status) {
    if (isset($_POST['billing_phone'])) {

        $coupon_code = false;
        // Over here, check if the posted phone number is in your api.

        if ($phonenumber_in_api) {

            switch ($customer_status) {

                case 'silver':
                    $coupon_code = 'silver1';
                    break;

                case 'gold':
                    $coupon_code = 'gold1';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($coupon_code && !WC()->cart->has_discount($coupon_code)) {
        WC()->cart->apply_coupon($coupon_code);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'verify_api_phonenumber');
```

Comment: Should I insert this code in `function.php` in my wordpress?

Comment: Indeed, you can insert this in your functions.php for your theme, or create a simple plugin to do this for you.

Comment: Hi, having some confusion. There is 4 type of customer. How I can use logic here? like `if customerstatus = silver:  $coupon_code= silver1` `if customerstatus=gold: $coupon_code=gold1` If I add the code in `function.php` Do I need to also add the apply coupon programmatically codes?

Comment: You could use a switch statement or a if/else to loop over the types of customer. I've updated the answer accordingly. Your second question is not clear, I'm not sure what you mean.